# Is tachanun said at a bar mitzvah?

Tags: halacha, tachanun, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Is tachanun said at a bar mitzvah boy's *aliyah latorah* that takes place on a day when tachanun is normally said (basically Monday and Thursday)?

I've been to a few of these, and seen different cases. Once, tachanun was skipped because of a brit that day. Another time tachanun was said, but then someone said afterwards that maybe it shouldn't have been.
I think it might depend on when the actual birthday (*bo bayom*) is. (I've heard as much.)

So, what's the law, and what is the source/reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rivivos Efraim 8 page 400](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1082&st=&pgnum=420&hilite=) says that one should say Tachanun at a Bar Mitzva and also has a letter from Rabbi Nosson Gestetner which says that Tachanun should be said at a Bar Mitzva as it is not listed in Orach Chaim 131:4-6 as one of the times it should not be said.

See also [Minchas Yitzchak 8:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1600&st=&pgnum=322) where he mentions that the Minchas Elazar did not say Tachanun on the day of a Bar Mitzva, however he says that one should say.

Answer (score 6):

R' Ovadia Yosef in Yabia Omer 1:27 says that a Bar Mitzvah boy entering mitzva-hood is like a chosson entering the chuppah and therefore one does not say *tachanun* on a bar-mitzvah.

Comment: Is this just for the *bo bayom*, or at the celebration, whenever that might be?

Comment: @Scimonster the _bo bayom_ - when he becomes chayav in mitzvos.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/letters/default_cdo/aid/2083756/jewish/Tachanun-for-the-Bar-Mitzvah-Boy.htm

A letter from the Rebbi saying to say tachanun at a barmitzva.

> Thus, while reaching Bar Mitzvah is indeed a great Yom Tov, the Bar Mitzvah boy does say Tachnun on this occasion,

Although it seems to be an ashkenaz yes, sefardi no machloket, backed up by sources in other peoples answers.